Rooting Lineage OS through local update?
I'm considering to root my Fairphone 3 running Android 13 on /e/OS (a close Lineage OS derivative). However, I don't wish to wipe my data by unlocking the bootloader, so I had the following idea to circumvent it:

On the official download site [1], find the link of the update file named IMG-e-2.4.1-t-official-FP3.zip (may contain additional numbers) and remove the string IMG from the address. [2] Download the file.
Extract the boot.img from the e-2.4.1-t-official-FP3.zip.
Patch the boot.img with Magisk.
Inside the e-2.4.1-t-official-FP3.zip, replace the official boot.img with the Magisk-patched one.
Go to settings ➡️ updater ➡️ “apply local update”, and select the patched e-2.4.1-t-official-FP3.zip.

Could anything unintended happen if I just ignored the vbmeta.img that is also present in e-2.4-t-official-FP3.zip?
(I hesitate to install Magisk via recovery, because it's not recommend on modern devices. Feel free to correct me if that method is still safe on my device.)
I foresee three possible error scenarios:

Android recognises the e-2.4-t-official-FP3.zip as “corrupted” and refuses to update.
Android does not refuse to apply the update, but fails to flash the boot partition due to the locked bootloader, possibly bricking the device.
While updating, Android automatically unlocks the bootloader to flash the boot partition, wiping my data without prior notice.

What will happen? Should I just try it?
[1] Please note that various /e/OS services are currently offline, including the update download site: https://mastodon.social/@murena/113272432488332874
[2]  Background: Builds that start with IMG are fastboot images that cannot be imported as local updates in the updater app:

IMG-e-2.2-t-20240715417772-stable-FP5.zip is a fastboot package. It doesn't support installing via updater app. Download e-2.2-t-20240715417772-stable-FP5.zip then try sideloading.
– https://gitlab.e.foundation/e/backlog/-/issues/8160#note_576544


if you have /e/OS installed with locked bootloader means you had once unlocked bootloader, installed custom keys and ROM and then relocked bootloader? Is vbmeta enabled or disabled on your phone? Note that on recent phones the partition to be patched is not always boot.img. Instead on some phones you have to patch init_boot.

After buying the Fairphone in 2019, I obtained a bootloader unlock code from Fairphone's support website, flashed /e/OS and (immediately after installation) re-locked the bootloader in the developer settings. What does it mean if vbmeta “is enabled” and how to check it? In the update .zip file, there is only a boot.img and no file named init_boot.
